# calculate start and end of working, grep in logfile

Tags: bash, shell

I need to know when I can do a maintance on a frequently used system. All I can check is a logfile, where I can see when the users are starting and ending there work in average. 
I need to do this for weekdays, saturday and sunday. 
I know how to grep these information but I don't know how to separate weekdays from weekends and how to build an average from the timestamps. 
Can anyone help me with that please?
 Kind regards

Edit: More information as requested

Here is my script so far:

```
i=14
while i >=0
    do dow=$(date -d "-$i day" +%A)
        if [ $dow = "Saturday" ] || [ $dow = "Sunday" ]
        then i=$((i-1))
        fi
        beginnweek+=(`zgrep T400: logfile|grep -v 'T811:Icinga'|head -n 1|cut -d " " -f2`)
        endweek+=(`zgrep T400: logfile|grep -v 'T811:Icinga'|tail -n 1|cut -d " " -f2`)
        i=$((i-1))
    done

###calculate average beginn and end - Thats what missing

i=14
while i >=0
    do dow=$(date -d "-$i day" +%A)
        if [ $dow = "Monday" ] || [ $dow = "Tuesday" ] || [ $dow = "Wednesday" ] || [ $dow = "Thursday" ] || [ $dow = "Friday" ] || [ $dow = "Sunday" ]
        then i=$((i-1))
        fi
        beginnSat+=(`zgrep T400: logfile|grep -v 'T811:Icinga'|head -n 1|cut -d " " -f2`)
        endSat+=(`zgrep T400: logfile|grep -v 'T811:Icinga'|tail -n 1|cut -d " " -f2`)
        i=$((i-1))
    done

###calculate average beginn and end - Thats what missing    

i=14
while i >=0
    do dow=$(date -d "-$i day" +%A)
        if [ $dow = "Monday" ] || [ $dow = "Tuesday" ] || [ $dow = "Wednesday" ] || [ $dow = "Thursday" ] || [ $dow = "Friday" ] || [ $dow = "Saturday" ]
        then i=$((i-1))
        fi
        beginnSun+=(`zgrep T400: logfile|grep -v 'T811:Icinga'|head -n 1|cut -d " " -f2`)
        endSun+=(`zgrep T400: logfile|grep -v 'T811:Icinga'|tail -n 1|cut -d " " -f2`)
        i=$((i-1))
    done

###calculate average beginn and end - Thats what missing
```

I'm working with
GNU bash, version 4.2.46
on SLES and with
GNU bash, version 3.1.17

The logfiles are looking like this:

```
19/10/2018 04:00:03.175 : [32631] INFO  : (8) >>\\\\\\\\\\T090:NOPRINT,NOSAVE|T400:551200015480|T811:Icinga|T8904:001|T8905:001|//////////
19/10/2018 07:17:19.501 : [4935] INFO  : >>\\\\\\\\\\T021:datamax|T050:software|T051:V 1.0|T101:|T400:428568605212|T520:00000000|T510:|T500:|T545:19.10.2018||T821:DE|PRINTINFO:|PRINT1:|PRINT0:intermec pf4i.int01|//////////
```

Comment: Probably. Please show samples of the log file and the code you have so far. Also please state your Operating System.

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you boil down your problem. Show us a small example of your input files. You said »where I can see when the users are starting and ending there work *in average*«. If the log files contain only the average, then there is no way to separate just the sundays.

Comment: I've put some more information in my question. Sorry I didn't do that right away.

Comment: @Socowi  There are complete timestamps when a user has made an action, as you now can see in the example.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should ask yourself if you really want to use an average. An average makes only sense if all users login at morning, stay logged in over noon, and logout at evening. If you have logouts distributed all over the day the average logout time is meaningless.
But even in such an idealized case you shouldn't start maintenance right after the average logout time since around 50% of the users would still be logged in at that time.

I would rather visualize logins as bars and determine a good maintenance time by hand. [ranwhen.py](https://github.com/p-e-w/ranwhen) (see picture below) is a very nice tool to display when your system was up. Maybe you can find something similar for logins or adapt the tool yourself.

[image: ranwhen.py]

Nevertheless, here's what you asked for:

## Parsing The Logs

Instead of parsing the log manually, I would advise you to use the `last` tool, which prints the last logins in a simpler format. Since you are on Linux, there should be an `-F` option for `last` to print dates prefixed with their weekday. With `-R` we suppress some unneeded information. The output of `last -FR` looks as follows:

```
socowi   pts/5        Fri Oct 19 17:42:16 2018   still logged in
reboot   system boot  Fri Oct 19 14:34:44 2018   still running
alice    pts/2        Fri Oct 19 10:35:05 2018 - Fri Oct 19 11:51:03 2018  (01:15)
alice    tty7         Fri Oct 19 10:24:32 2018 - Fri Oct 19 11:51:52 2018  (01:27)
bob      tty7         Fri Oct 19 10:04:21 2018 - Fri Oct 19 10:14:01 2018  (00:09)
reboot   system boot  Fri Oct 19 12:03:34 2018 - Fri Oct 19 11:51:55 2018  (00:-11)
carol    tty7         Fri Oct 19 08:10:49 2018 - down                      (01:50)
dave     tty7         Thu Oct 18 12:48:12 2018 - crash                     (04:28)

wtmp begins Tue Oct 16 12:38:03 2018
```

To extract the valid login and logout dates we use the following functions.

```
onlyUsers() { last -FR | head -n -2 | grep -Ev '^reboot '; }
onlyDates() { grep -F :; }
loginDates() { onlyUsers | cut -c 23-46 | onlyDates; }
logoutDates() { onlyUsers | cut -c 50-73 | onlyDates; }
```

## Filter By Weekday

The functions `loginDates` and `logoutDates` print something like

```
Fri Oct 19 17:42:16 2018
Fri Oct 19 14:34:44 2018
[...]
Thu Oct 18 12:48:12 2018
```

Filtering out specific weekdays is pretty easy:

```
workweek() { grep -E 'Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri'; }
weekend() { grep -E 'Sat|Sun'; }
```

If you want all login dates on weekends, you would write `loginDates | weekend`.

## Computing An Average Time

To compute the average time from multiple dates, we first extract the time of day from the dates. Then we convert the HH:MM format to minutes since midnight. Computing an average of a list numbers is easy. Afterwards we convert back to HH:MM.

```
timeOfDay() { cut -c 12-16; }
timeToMins() { awk -F: '{print $1*60 + $2}'; }
minsToTime() { awk '{printf "%02d:%02d", $1/60, $1%60}'; }
avgMins() { awk '{s+=$1}END{printf "%d", s/NR}'; }
avgTime() { timeOfDay | timeToMins | avgMins | minsToTime; }
```

## Putting Everything Together

To get the average times just combine the commands as needed. Some examples:

```
# Average login times during workweeks 
avg="$(loginDates | workweek | avgTime)"
# Average logout times on weekends
avg="$(logoutDates | weekend | avgTime)"
```